# Django combine filter on two fields

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am relatively new to Django. I'm having problem when filtering data. I have two models, given below:

```
Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel)
    account_type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, max_length=30)

Transaction(models.Model):        
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='transaction')
    transaction_type = models.CharField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE, max_length=15)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**ACCOUT_TYPE** is:

```
ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
  (0, 'Asset'),
  (1, 'Liabilities'),
  (2, 'Equity'),
  (3, 'Income'),
  (4, 'Expense')
)
```

I want to filter all the transactions where the account type is `Income` and `Expense` within a given date range. How can I combine those filters in Django?

I have tried like this:

```
income_account = Account.objects.filter(account_type=3)
expense_account = Account.objects.filter(account_type=4)
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(Q(
  account=income_account,
  date_created__gte=request.data['start_date'],
  date_created__lte=request.data['end_date']
) & Q(
  account=expense_account,
date_created__gte=request.data['start_date'],
date_created__lte=request.data['end_date'])).order_by('date_created')
```

But it's not working. It raises the following error:

```
  ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`income_account` and `expense_account` is not single object, it is a list of objects. So instead of this `account=income_account` and this `account=expense_account` try to use `in`: `account__in=income_account` and `account__in=expense_account`.
Also you probably could simplify queryset like this:

```
accounts = Account.objects.filter(Q(account_type=3) | Q(account_type=4))
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    account__in=accounts,
    date_created__gte=request.data['start_date'],
    date_created__lte=request.data['end_date']
).order_by('date_created')
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having multiple querysets, you can have only one, as `Q` allows `OR`ing of filters. You could do:

```
Transaction.objects.filter(
    (Q(account__account_type=3) | Q(account__account_type=4)) &
    Q(date_created__range=[start_date, end_date])
)
```

The `__range` can be used to get dates between the specified `start_date` and `end_date`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `in` to lookup records by multiple values. So, if you want `Transaction` where `ACCOUNT_TYPE` are `Income, Expense`you can use it like this.

```
Transaction.objects.filter(Q(account__in=[3,4]) & Q(date_created__gte=request.data['start_date']) & Q(date_created__lte=request.data['end_date'])).order_by('date_created')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:-

```
result = Account.objects.filter((account_type__in['Income','Expense'])
                   OR
result = Account.objects.filter((account_type__in['0','4'])
```

I have put 0 and 4 as string because you have mention account_type as CharField.